# mpi4py Send characters

Tags: python, mpi, mpi4py

I'd like to use the faster Send (not the slower send) method to transmit some characters from one process to another, but haven't been able to get a working solution with mpi4py (restricted to using this language, Python3)

Here's my toy code - if anyone can point out what I'm doing wrong (and how to fix it), I'd be very grateful.

```
from mpi4py import MPI
import numpy
from array import array
comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
if comm.rank == 0:
    comm.Send([b'hello',MPI.CHAR],dest=1)
elif comm.rank == 1:
    buf = array('b')*255
    r = comm.Recv([buf,MPI.CHAR],source=0)
    print(r)
```

For reference, I also tried the code here (didnt work): https://groups.google.com/g/mpi4py/c/LDHbzApI55c/m/gENCO-_HAwUJ

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your buffer `buf` in this case is not big enough to fit your message when it tries to receive it as it is of length 0.

The solution here is to use a `bytearray`  as you can initialise it on a fixed size, so your example will be:

```
from mpi4py import MPI

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
if comm.rank == 0:
    comm.Send([b'hello',MPI.CHAR],dest=1)
elif comm.rank == 1:
    buf = bytearray(256)
    comm.Recv([buf,MPI.CHAR],source=0)
    # Decode the string to remove the empty characters from bytearray
    print(buf.decode('utf-8'))
```

Also notice that the Recv does not return a value so r will be empty. The result will be saved directly to `buf`

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! Just tried this solution on my computer, works like a charm. I'd noticed that there were similar questions floating around but no working solution that I could find. Hope this is useful for someone else too.

Comment: For a general solution, instead of in-place conversion of the string to bytes, I used 

`string = 'hello'` 
and
`comm.Send([string.encode('utf-8'), MPI.CHAR], dest=1)`

on the sending process